# Smooth panning problem -- low touches per second

Tags: android, events, touch, panning

If I quickly swipe my finger around the screen, android only gives me about 15 different touch events per second.

This means that if I have an image panning around to follow my finger, it will only move 15 times per second, which is essentially 15 frames per second.

Google maps pans much more smoothly than 15 frames per second.

Does anyone know how it is possible to make panning smoother, when the android system won't provide you more than 15 touch events or so per second?

Comment: Interpolate between each event?

Comment: Your swipe lasts 1 second and during that time only 15 events?

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is use an integrated methods of Path class: quadTo() or cubicTo().
Check this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html